# Recover Custom Post Type Data

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created CPT using CPT UI plugin and suddenly I lost all the important data. I don't have any backup and I need it backup. Is there any I can get it backup? I have SQL backup of last week.

Moreover I am seeing Count on CPT categories but they are showing Empty on main CPT page. for example CPT:

Animals --> showing  (0) posts

Animal Categories is showing 100 counts that means It has data but something has hide it. I remember I updated Permalinks but I don't remember the previous settings

Comment: simply recreate your post type with same name, 
they will show up in wp admin menu

Comment: how? can you please explain? Should I recreate the Custom Post Type? or the post it had

Comment: I created post inside that CPT but it has not returned old posts. Should I delete the CPT itself and then recreate? I am afraid If I will lost the count too

Comment: i want to create a query for you, use it to get you post text info, and titles etc..., i will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

use this `sqlQuery` in your `SQL Database` (phpMyadmin or ...) and you will get a list of your `custom post type` posts with their info:

```
SELECT *
FROM {table prefix}_posts
WHERE post_type =  'your_custom_post_type_name'
AND post_status =  'publish'
```

your `{table prefix}` can be `wp` or some thing else if you've change it on wp setup step you can check it in your `Database` or `wp-config.php` file in your wp root.

you can replace `*` in query with whatever field name you want for example:

```
post_content, post_title, post_excerpt
```

to only get fields that you need.